# Bootstrap responsive footer image align

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, image, footer

I'm making a responsive footer, but I'm stuck at an image in the footer.
The left (red) side is good for now, not responsive but that's something for later. At the right one (blue) I want the image, the three circles floated to right, just like the left one but than floated right. But I can't get it done. 
Second picture I've uploaded is the image in the footer that I can't get in the snippet. Anyone an idea?
[image]

[image: this is the footer image]

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <style>
        .nopadding {
            padding: 0 !important;
            margin: 0 !important;
            bottom: 0 !important;
        }
        #footer{
            width: 100%;
            height: 80px;
            background-color: black;
            bottom: 0;
            left: 0;
            position: absolute;
        }
        #links{
            background-color: red;
        }
        #rechts{
            background-color: blue;
            float: right;
        }
        #links img{
            width: 20%;
            float: left;
            margin-top: 6%;
            margin-right: 7.5%;
        }
        #links p{
            color: white;
            font-weight: bold;
            font-size: 1.2em;
            margin-left: 5%;
            line-height: 80px;
            margin-bottom: -0.1em;
        }
        #rechts img{
            width: 20%;
            //float: right;
            margin-top: 6%;
            margin-right: 7.5%;
            position: relative;
        }
        #rechts p{
            color: white;
            //text-align: right;
            float: right;
            font-weight: bold;
            font-size: 1.2em;
            margin-left: 5%;
            line-height: 80px;
            margin-bottom: -0.1em;
        }

        /* Medium devices (desktops, 992px and up) */
    @media (min-width: 767px) and (max-width : 992px) { 

    }

    /* Large devices (large desktops, 1200px and up) */
    @media (max-width: 1200px) { 

    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12" id="footer">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-6 nopadding" id="links">
                                <img src="img/footer.png"><p>EXAMPLE 100A, 1234 AB EXAMPLE</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6 nopadding" id="rechts">
                                <img src="img/footer.png"><p>TEL. +01 (2)345-678912</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js "></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js "></script> 
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have take 2 images 
1) [image: Footer left image] This is left image of footer.
2) [image: Footer Right image] This is Right image of footer.

Now join these 2 images inside a (col-)div and you will get output as shown in these image [image: This is final output image]

---

## Note: i have also made it responsive as per your screen size.If need changes then ask me.

```
    <html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js "></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js "></script>
    <style>
        div.img1{
            background-image:url("footerimage1.png");
            background-repeat:no-repeat;
            background-size:cover;
            height:150px;
        }

        div.img2{
            background-image:url("footerimage2.png");
            background-repeat:no-repeat;
            background-size:cover;
            height:150px;
        }

        .heading1{
            margin-top:75px;
            text-align:right;
            color:#fff;
            font-weight:900;
        }

        .heading2{
            margin-top:75px;
            text-align:right;
            color:#fff;
            font-weight:900;
        }

        @media only screen and (max-device-width: 768px) and (orientation: portrait){
            div.img1{
                background-image:url("footerimage1.png");
                background-repeat:no-repeat;
                background-size:cover;
                height:150px;
                width:50%;
                float:left;
            }

            div.img2{
                background-image:url("footerimage2.png");
                background-repeat:no-repeat;
                background-size:cover;
                height:150px;
                width:50%;
                float:left;
            }

            .heading1{
                margin-top:75px;
                text-align:right;
                color:#fff;
                font-weight:900;
                font-size:11px;
            }

            .heading2{
                margin-top:75px;
                text-align:right;
                color:#fff;
                font-weight:900;
                font-size:11px;
            }
        }

        @media only screen and (max-device-width: 1024px) and (orientation: landscape){
            .heading1{
                margin-top:75px;
                text-align:right;
                color:#fff;
                font-weight:900;
                font-size:12px;
            }

            .heading2{
                margin-top:75px;
                text-align:right;
                color:#fff;
                font-weight:900;
                font-size:14px;
            }
        }

        @media only screen and (max-device-width: 414px) and (orientation: portrait){
            div.img1{
                background-image:url("footerimage1.png");
                background-repeat:no-repeat;
                background-size:cover;
                height:230px;
                width:100%;
            }

            div.img2{
                background-image:url("footerimage2.png");
                background-repeat:no-repeat;
                background-size:cover;
                height:230px;
                width:100%;
            }

            .heading1{
                margin-top:90px;
                text-align:right;
                color:#fff;
                font-weight:900;
                font-size:28px;
            }

            .heading2{
                margin-top:90px;
                text-align:right;
                color:#fff;
                font-weight:900;
                font-size:28px;
            }
        }

             /* Medium devices (desktops, 992px and up) */
        @media (min-width: 767px) and (max-width : 992px) { 
            div.img1{
                background-image:url("footerimage1.png");
                background-repeat:no-repeat;
                background-size:cover;
                height:230px;
                width:50%;
                float:left;
            }

            div.img2{
                background-image:url("footerimage2.png");
                background-repeat:no-repeat;
                background-size:cover;
                height:230px;
                width:50%;
                float:left;
            }

            .heading1{
                margin-top:170px;
                text-align:center;
                color:#fff;
                font-weight:900;
                font-size:18px;
            }

            .heading2{
                margin-top:170px;
                text-align:center;
                color:#fff;
                font-weight:900;
                font-size:18px;
            }
        }

        /* Large devices (large desktops, 1200px and up) */
        @media (max-width: 1200px) { 
            .heading1{
                margin-top:60px;
                text-align:right;
                color:#fff;
                font-weight:900;
                font-size:16px;
            }

            .heading2{
                margin-top:60px;
                text-align:right;
                color:#fff;
                font-weight:900;
                font-size:18px;
            }
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <footer>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 img1">
                <h4 class="heading1">Example 100A, 1234 AB EXAMPLE</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 img2">
                <h4 class="heading2">TEL. +01(2)345-678912</h4>
            </div>
        </div>
    </footer> 
</body>
</html>
```